# Java TrayIcon.displayMessage() does not work on Windows XP

Tags: java, windows, swing, system-tray

I'm writing an application that runs in the System Tray and notifies the user (i.e. makes one of those bubbles pop up) when something happens. The only problem is that the notifications only seem to work on Windows 7, and not Windows XP.

I've tested it on 2 Windows 7 computers (they've both worked) and 4 Windows XP computers (none of them have worked). No notification bubble is shown, and (as far as I know) no exceptions are thrown and everything else works as it should. I've even tested it on a Mac, and it worked, but it wasn't too pretty.

Here is a sample of my code.

```
private static TrayIcon trayIcon;
...
trayIcon = new TrayIcon(trayImage.getImage());
...
if (!SystemTray.isSupported())
{
    System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
    return;
}
final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
trayIcon.setToolTip("Widget Name Here [" + role + "]");
...
try
{
    tray.add(trayIcon);
}
catch (AWTException e)
{
    System.err.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
    return;
}
...
//Here's where it doesn't work on XP
trayIcon.displayMessage("Connection error",
                "Could not connect to server, please check your internet/VPN "
                + "connection", TrayIcon.MessageType.ERROR);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: Ok, I've just confirmed that it's not a problem with my program, but a problem with the XP installations I've been testing them on. I ran the TrayIconDemo.java program found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html) on an XP computer and none of the notifications worked. I'm starting to think there's nothing I can do to get it to work on one of these computers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I've finally found the solution to my problem. It turned out that the following key was set to `0` (false) by default on the installations I was testing on:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\EnableBalloonTips
```

To enable the notification bubbles, simply set the value to `1`.

Comment: from where I can set the value? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I have Windows XP and working on system tray application. I have just added `displayMessage()` and it works just fine for me. Try to simplify your application. I am sure it will work. The find a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I had a similar problem before, except the notifications stopped working for no apparent reason on Windows 7. I only managed to fix it by reverting to an earlier version of the program that I knew worked. I never managed to find out what the problem was that stopped them from popping up. I just hope I don't have to lose weeks of work just to figure this out :/

Comment: After some further investigation, it seems like it might be the OS itself causing the issue (all of the XP computers I've tried it on so far are a special enterprise installation). It seems like the OS actually doesn't show any popup notifications of any kind, there have been multiple times when I've heard the Windows 'pop' notification sound for something like Windows Update, but no bubble has shown up. I guess the only thing to do now is to try it on a non-enterprise XP installation and if it works then.

Comment: Yeah, I've confirmed it's not a problem with my program. See the update in the question.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: you didn't mentioned JRE version `System try required Java6`

this should be comment, but this is restrict for chars lenght

maybe, there is another reason in case of when Java updates are distributed by some of administrations tool for AD or ZenWorks, then sometimes (on both win7/Xp) is needed un-install all java instalactions and install fresh JRE manually (but stable 1.6.022 my view), sw distibutions ends without error, but all (???) classes/methods/changes cames from Java6 weren't accesible, on partial (RowSorter etc...) test ends with error, and I never search for knows Bugs on MS, Novell ...